# WAN Simulation for Web Site Testing

Tags: simulation, wan

I am searching a low cost WAN network simulation software for testing my website before production deployment. It should have following features
1. Controls bandwidth.
2. Can insert latency, jitter.
3. Can do some packet loss also (Desirable).

Can anyone suggest me windows based software that is and free or low cost?

**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [WanEM](http://wanem.sourceforge.net/).  It's free.

Comment: Is this available for Windows?

Answer (score 0):

The Network Emulation Toolkit (NEWT) is available on Windows.

http://blog.mrpol.nl/2010/01/14/network-emulator-toolkit/

It provides the following features:

- Bandwidth control
- Variable latency and jitter
- Packet loss
- Packet reordering
- Bit errors
- Intermittent disconnection